# CSRF filter blocking AJAX Post request. How to set httprequest parameter for AJAX request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, csrf

I am currently trying to send an AJAX post request, however I am unable to do so, because of my CSRF Filter. I have tried a bunch of things, but the filter always blocks the request. Here is what I think is close, but for some reason it doesn't work... I am getting a valid CSRF string from my method getCSRFTokenValue().

Is my line -> data: { 'CSRF_TOKEN': getCSRFTokenValue()} adding the request parameter like it should, or am I supposed to be doing something else? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. Thank you in advance.

```
function getCSRFTokenValue() {return "${CSRF_TOKEN}"};

$('#toggleUserToType').on('click', function(event){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/capstone/api/toggleUserType?email=" + $('#emailInput').val(),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'CSRF_TOKEN': getCSRFTokenValue()}
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#userFirstName').val(data.firstName);
        $('#userLastName').val(data.lastName);
        $('#userPhone').val(data.phoneNumber);
        $('#userType').val(data.userType===1?"Regular App-User":"Employee");
    }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Method handling the post requests:

```
private void handlePOST(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        String sessionToken = (String)httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute(CSRF_TOKEN);
        String requestToken = (String)httpRequest.getParameter(CSRF_TOKEN);
        if(sessionToken == null || sessionToken.equals(requestToken) == false) {
            httpResponse.sendError(400);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't put your token into data, put it into headers. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434971/how-set-up-headers-in-ajax-post-request-to-include-csrf-token?rq=1

Comment: Tokens should be in header using ( Authorization or Access-Token keys)

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/capstone/api/toggleUserType?email=" + $('#emailInput').val(),
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
   "CSRF_TOKEN": getCSRFTokenValue()
  }
 })  
             
I tried this and it still didn't work. If I put it in the header, what is the key supposed to be?

the statement if(sessionToken == null || sessionToken.equals(requestToken) == false) {
            httpResponse.sendError(400);
        }

is returning false I think because it's not finding the requestToken parameter

Comment: It's X-CSRF-TOKEN

Comment: Hey MGorgon, I figured it out! Thank you very much. See Stephen Ostermiller's response on the thread that you linked. Although I am still not sure why the header X-CSRF-TOKEN or CSRF_TOKEN did not work for me, encoding it like Stephen suggested in the other post did the trick. Thank you again and have a great night!!